# Is the 'go places' possible?

Tags: grammaticality

I saw the sentence like:

It can go places where people cannot.

Is this sentence grammatically right?

Comment: Yes, that is a grammatical construction.  It can reach places that people cannot (reach). For example, a camera on a long pole can be inserted into conduit to look for problems. The camera can go places that people cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Users of all languages show a tendency to drop words that are not entirely necessary. English, in particular, has a great deal of redundancy.

Your example is a shortened version of this:

"It can go [to] places where people cannot [go].